# Rails 4 action_mailer host

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, config

For Rails 4, I am using `config.action_mailer.asset_host = "http://localhost:3000"` in

`config > environments > development.rb`

to load assets to my mailer.

Is there a better value than a hardcoded url? I imagine there should be one since I would not use this value in my `production.rb`. What is the code to find the current host url in rails config?

Answer (score 0):

If you deploy to a known host, you can put it directly in production.rb

But if you really need to read it from the url, than you check this out

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Request.html#method-i-original_url

Comment: This seems to be deprecated and unavailable in Rails 4. I am gettinga no method error using request.original_url.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using [SendGrid](https://sendgrid.com/docs/Integrate/Frameworks/rubyonrails.html), inside `config/environment.rb` file specify your ActionMailer settings to point to SendGrid’s servers.

```
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
  :user_name => 'your_sendgrid_username',
  :password => 'your_sendgrid_password',
  :domain => 'yourdomain.com',
  :address => 'smtp.sendgrid.net',
  :port => 587,
  :authentication => :plain,
  :enable_starttls_auto => true
  }
```